# Where using archimedean axiom is hidden in proof of existence of supremum of upper bounded set of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

Here is my proof of existence of least upper bound for upper bounded set of real numbers. I am using the axiomatic model of real numbers with 2 axioms - the first one is archimedean axiom and the second one is axiom about nested segments (intersection of nested segments is nonempty).

Let $X$ - nonempty upper bounded set of real numbers, and $Y$ set of upper boundes of $X$. Let's take an arbitrary $x \in X, y \in Y$ and $I_1 = [x_1, y_1]$. Consider $I_n = [x_n, y_n]$ the following way:

If $(x_n + y_n) / 2 \in Y$, then $x_{n+1} = x_n, \; y_{n+1} =(x_n + y_n) / 2$, else $y_{n+1} = y_{n}, \; x_{n+1} = (x_n + y_n) / 2$.

Using axiom of nested segments we obtain that $\cap I_n$ is nonempty. Moreover $|I_n| \to 0$, so $\cap I_n = M$ - just one point. Let's see, that $M$ is upper bound: $x \in X$ can't be greater than $M$, because in such case for some great $n$ it's true that $y_n < x$ (because $I_n \to 0$), contradiction to the fact that $y_n$ is upper bound (by constraction). The fact that $M$ is least upper bounde is obvious, there doesn't exist upper bounde $y \in Y$ such that $y < M$ because we can find a natural number $n$ such that $y < x_n$ (because $|I_n| \to 0$), which can't be.

I know that in proof of this fact we must use both of this axioms, but it seems to me that i used only nested segments axiom. May be any mistake in my proof? Or where i hiddenly used archimedean axiom?

Comment: What do you mean by $|I_n|$ and why should it go to $0$?

Comment: $|I_n| = |x_n - y_n|$ and it tends to zero because $|I_n| = |I_1| / 2^n$

Comment: Well how do you know that $|I_1|/2^n$ goes to $0$?